# Incorrect permissions assigned to file when created from Windows computer

Tags: permissions, mount, nfs, umask

I have a Linux server with a NFS share.  User1 and Group1 have rwx permissions to the folder.  When I create a file on the Linux host as user1, it has the correct permissions.  On the Windows machine, I have created the AnonymousUid and AnonymousGid registry entries with the UID and GID of user1 and group1.  When I create a file on the Linux NFS share, it assigns rwxr-x--x whereas from the Linux host it creates it with rwxrwx--x.

How do I correct this issue.  I map the NFS share using windows map features and if I go to the mapped drive property, I see the following which is correct:

[image]

[image]

Below is what I see on the Linux server:

[image]

Gid 30928 is Gid for sapsys

Comment: Welcome to the site. the issue is caused on the windows side, I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to superuser.com

Comment: I don't believe it should be closed because the source is the Linux and it is Linux privileges that are used.  Could you keep it open for a couple of days and see if anyone comments.

Comment: Even if it is Linux related, the problem happen on the Windows side and need to be fixed on the Windows, don't worry the question won't be deleted quickly... on superuser.com (same sites network) your question would get more attention and answers from users of Windows... (this is just a matter of stackexchange questions organisations)

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear, do you need files creation with rwxrwx--x on the Linux side? please edit your question with a little question summary of your request to clarify the situation

Comment: Essentially it looks like you would need the equivalent of the `umask` setting for the Windows NFS client. Also note the plus signs at the end of the permissions in the Linux `ls -l` output - that suggests the files have ACLs on them. A directory may have a "default ACL" that can override the permissions of new files created in that directory - perhaps something like that is in effect or could be adjusted to get the permissions you want. `getfacl` and `setfacl` are the commands for manipulating ACLs.

Comment: I believe this question should stay open : the problem solution will probably be found in the settings of the nfs share on the linux nfs server. Having the question here makes sense for this part, imo.